# Property 'p' does not exist on type 'T' in ngFor trackBy

Tags: angular

I have a project and frontend was developed via `@angular/cli: 1.1.3`. Everything worked fine until I had tried compile the project in prod mode(`ng build -prod`). At places where I used `*ngFor` directive with `trackBy` token I got the error like this

> ...src/app/app.component.ts.AppComponent.html (4,11): Property 'p'
>   does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.

If I remove 'trackBy' statement error will disappear. 
I've repeated this error in blank project to attach it here.

**AppComponent** class declaration:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let p of ppp | async;trackBy: p?.s">
        <h2>{{p.s}}</h2>
      </li>
    </ul>`,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ppp: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.ppp = Observable.create((observer) => {
      observer.next([{s: "0"}]);
      setTimeout(function () {
        observer.next([{s: "1"}, {s: "2"}, {s: "3"}]);
      }, 2000);
    });
  }    
}
```

**AppModule** class declaration:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Is there an approach to call successfully `ng build -prod` and keep **trackBy** statements;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`trackBy` must be a function-valued property on the component. Read [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngfor-with-trackby), which is perfectly clear.

> Add a method to the component that **returns the value `NgFor` should track.**

```
<li *ngFor="let p of ppp | async; trackBy: trackByS">
    <h2>{{p.s}}</h2>
</li>

public trackByS(p) { return p.s; }
```

The `trackBy` part of your code did not actually do what you thought it, even when not compiling with AoT. `trackBy: p?.s` tried to access a property `p` on the component, which does not exist, so it was ignored. It's just that AoT compiles the template logic, which exposed the error.

Comment: Thanks for this - I could have quite easily looked at the documentation, but ended up here from Google. Just looked at the documentation, and their most recent (as at 03/2019) example function is shown with `index` as the first argument: `trackByHeroes(index: number, hero: Hero): number { return hero.id; }` - just in case anyone copy/pastes the above code and gets caught out :)